# Generate Postgresql schema using generator like an ORM (like ActiveRecord or Ecto etc)

Tags: database, postgresql, database-design, orm, database-schema

I'm wondering if there is a software (a generator, a web page, an executable, a command line, etc.) that allows me to generate a Postgresql scheme since I'm not an expert and I wouldn't know where to start.

I searched a lot and found several modelers, but even those are hard to use: I don't really know what kind of indices to use, what to choose as types of fields, etc.

An ORM helps a lot (Rails ActiveRecord or Ecto for Elixir or Gorm or TypeORM for JS) help a lot people who don't know what to choose and give a good starting dose, especially for POC or fast MVP.

Is there anything that generates pretty good SQL schema like ActiveRecord around? Or am I forced to use that?

If the project is funded it is obvious that there will be an ad hoc team, but for a good POC you can also start this way, right?

NOTE: the project doesn't use Rails or Ruby at all.

Comment: If you start with an object model defined with Java classes, you can use JDX ORM to easily generate a relational schema for Postgres or any other relational database. Disclaimer: I am the architect of JDX ORM for Java.

Comment: If you want great functionality, you're probably going to have to pay. I understand money may be tight, but most licenses for paid schema designers are only a couple hundred bucks. You'll probably save way more time and money going that route. (or you could learn how to write schemas with SQL. It's really not that hard.)